# Measure angle of multiple concentric lines

Tags: python, opencv

I have a series of concentric lines. I'm trying to measure the angle these lines make in aggregate.  I've tried to illustrate this in an image below. If I were to draw a line (visualized in green) across the centers of each of the black curved line, what would be the angle of the green line. So far I've come up with this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('test_2.png')  

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)

# Detect lines using HoughLinesP
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=1000)

# Iterate through lines and calculate the angle
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    angle_rad = np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)
    angle_deg = np.degrees(angle_rad)
    
    # Draw the line on the image
    cv2.line(image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    
    # Annotate the image with the measured angle
    cv2.putText(image, f'Angle: {np.mean(angle_deg):.2f}', (x1, y1 - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (255, 0, 0), 1)

# Display annotated image
cv2.imshow('Line Angles', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results:
[image]

As you can see, this doesn't really capture what I want. The angle I'm looking to capture is represented by the green line (draw a line through the center of the curved lines — what's the angle?):
[image]

Here is the original image:
[image]

Comment: You need to separate your problem into two parts: which algorithm do you want to use to determine the angle, and which coding techniques do you want to use to implement the algorithm. We can help with the second part.

Comment: How about finding the centre of each arc, then calculating line of best fit through those 7 points?

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's a great idea. How?

Comment: You've gone very quiet. Did you try my suggestion? Any luck?

Answer (score 2):

I propose to invert your image so your arcs become white lines on black background because OpenCV looks for white foreground objects on a black background. Then use `cv.findcontours()` to find each of your arcs, and get its centroid. Save all the centroids and use Numpy's `polyfit()` to fit a straight line through the centroids:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image and derive greyscale version
im = cv.imread('arcs.png')
grey = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold and invert
_, thr = cv.threshold(grey, 128,255,type=cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-thresh.png', thr)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv.findContours(thr, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# xs[] and ys[] are the centres that we are going to fit
xs = []
ys = []
for c in contours:
   M = cv.moments(c)
   cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
   cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
   print(f'Centroid: cX={cX}, cY={cY}')
   # Mark centre in red
   im[cY-9:cY+9, cX-9:cX+9] = [0,0,255]
   # Save point so we can fit a line 
   xs.append(cX)
   ys.append(cY)
   
   # Get bounding box and draw it on in blue
   x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(c)
   print(f'x={x}, y={y}, w={w}, h={h}')
   cv.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), [255,0,0], 3)
cv.imwrite('result.png', im)

# Now fit a line to x[] and y[] - the order is 1 as it's a straight line
z = np.polyfit(xs,ys,1)
print(f'Equation of line is y = {z[0]}*x + {z[1]}')
print(f'Angle of line is {math.degrees(math.atan(z[0]))}')
```

**Output**

```
Centroid: cX=1363, cY=2112
x=1267, y=2054, w=223, h=158
Centroid: cX=1276, cY=1971
x=1098, y=1857, w=412, h=313
Centroid: cX=1193, cY=1827
x=937, y=1688, w=594, h=412
Centroid: cX=1085, cY=1658
x=740, y=1484, w=822, h=532
Centroid: cX=949, cY=1487
x=620, y=1288, w=850, h=643
Centroid: cX=858, cY=1329
x=522, y=1041, w=911, h=841
Centroid: cX=763, cY=1168
x=423, y=845, w=1023, h=1002
Equation of line is y = 1.5434504697205325*x + -0.5448095425170528
Angle of line is 57.06083867565159
```

[image]

---

As an alternative to using the centroid of each arc, you could calculate the rotated rectangle that contains the arc (blue in diagram below), and take its rotation (theta in the code) and find the normal to the median of those angles:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Load image and derive greyscale version
im = cv.imread('arcs.png')
grey = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold and invert
_, thr = cv.threshold(grey, 128,255,type=cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-thresh.png', thr)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv.findContours(thr, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# xs[] and ys[] are the centres that we are going to fit
xs = []
ys = []
for c in contours:
   # Calculate moments so we can get the centroid
   M = cv.moments(c)
   cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
   cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
   print(f'Centroid: {cX=}, {cY=}')
   # Mark centre in red
   im[cY-9:cY+9, cX-9:cX+9] = [0,0,255]
   # Save point so we can fit a line 
   xs.append(cX)
   ys.append(cY)
   
   # Draw minimum area rotated rectangle containing this arc
   rect = cv.minAreaRect(c)
   (x,y),(width,height),theta = rect
   print(f'Theta: {theta}')
   box = cv.boxPoints(rect)
   box = np.int0(box)

   # draw minimum area rectangle (rotated rectangle)
   cv.drawContours(im,[box],0,(255,0,0),3)    

cv.imwrite('result.png', im)
```

[image]